# Trouble running tar from crontab

Tags: bash, debian, backup, cron

When I want to compress a folder manually I use the command:

```
tar -zcvf $dirBackup-$actualTime.tgz $dirBackup;
```

And it works perfectly. Also when I decompress the archive the result is correct.

But I have a problem when I run the same command from crontab: the resulting tgz only appears to contain an empty file.

```
crontab -l>> /home/user/Desktop/test/temp;
echo "$min $hour * * * tar -zcvf $dirBackup-$actualTime.tgz $dirBackup">> temp;
crontab temp;
```

Do I need to change anything in the crontab expression? Do I have to be root to run crontab?  The file temp is created correctly, and located in the right folder.

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: could you show how this job looks like in your crontab (not how you try to write it there)? the question appeared because you use env vars, and interesting what is under (e.g. relative path, full path?)

Comment: post the output of `crontab -l`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system, `crontab` jobs may or may not be run in your `$HOME` directory (in fact they are typically run either in `/` or in `/var/cron`).  Add a `cd $HOME;` before the `tar` command.

Comment: I did that, and it doesn't work. Maybe it could be cause of the privileges? I mean, it's necessary to be root to do the crontab?

Comment: You can check by running `crontab -l` again.

Comment: @Reaper To answer your question, firstly, it is not necessary to be root user to do the cronjob. The directory you are trying to access should be accessible from the context of that user. If it is not, then the permission issue will come into picture.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of the variables in the `echo` command you are using to add entry into the cron job. A sample script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

min=30
hour=17
dirBackup=/home/user/Desktop
actualTime=30-04-2015

crontab -l >> /home/user/temp
echo "$min $hour * * * tar -zcvf $dirBackup-$actualTime.tgz $dirBackup 2>&1 | tee /tmp/cron.log">> /home/user/temp;
crontab /home/user/temp;
```

The resulting tar file will be created in the user's HOME directory (user with which the cron is run).

To avoid getting into user permission issues, you can specify the user with which the cron is to be run using the following command:

```
crontab -u <username> <cron_file>
```

Comment: Actually im setting the values of min and hour from reading console. But i don't know why it doesn't work. They do the backup at the determinated time but it's an empty file. I read that sometimes it's necessary to set a new line in the crontab file. Is that true?

Comment: @Reaper Where from the value `dirBackup` is passed? Is the value of `dirBackup` sane?

Comment: @Reaper Do you receive any error? Try running the cron with errors redirected to a file. See my edit.

Comment: no error. It shows me the crontab tasks programmabled. All correct. The .tgz file is generated but it's empty. This is given me a terrible headache!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by empty? Is the source directory empty? Also please use absolute path for the temp file in which you are redirecting the output.